# Why are plots different on Wolfram|Alpha and Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving

I got to do a simple numerical solving of this non-linear and second order differential equation.

$\begin{align*}
x''(t)&=-3x'(t)\sqrt{\frac{(x´(t))^2}{6}+\frac{(1-e^{-x(t)\cdot\sqrt{2/3}})^2}{4}}
\end{align*}-\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}e^{-x(t)\cdot\sqrt{2/3}}(1-e^{-x(t)\cdot\sqrt{2/3}})$

with initial conditions $x(0)=5.352$ and $x'(0)=-1.033\cdot10^{-2}$. Therefore, I first tried using WolframAlpha, getting the next Plot Solutions.

[image]

However, I want to know more about the numerical values on the axis, and since I couldn't add them on WolframAlpha, I decided to do the problem on Mathematica, using $\text{NDSolve}$ with $\{t,0,150\}$. What I got is the following plot.

[image]

The image looks similar to the one plotted on WolframAlpha as the Plot Solution. However, wanting to extend the graph, I found Mathematica with a negative exponential solution, which is not the general behaviour I am looking for. Therefore, is there any problem with the $\text{NDSolve}$ or why are these plots of the exact same problem different?[image]

Another doubt is how to get the second plot from WolframAlpha on Mathematica? Since Mathematica does not give an explicit solution on this case, how do I make an $x'(t)\ \text{vs}\ x(t)$ plot on Mathematica using the solutions from the $\text{NDSolve}$?

The code was

```
NDSolve[{x''[t] + 
    3*x'[t]*Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + 1/4 - Exp[-x[t]*Sqrt[2/3]]/2 + 
      Exp[-2*x[t]*Sqrt[2/3]]/4] + 
    Sqrt[3/2]*Exp[-x'[t]*Sqrt[2/3]]*(1 - Exp[-x'[t]*Sqrt[2/3]]) == 0, 
  x'[0] == -0.010327936857938202, x[0] == 5.352343521285111}, x, {t, 
  0, 150}]

Plot[InterpolationFunction[x], {x, 0., 150.}]
```

Comment: Please post your Mathematica code.

Comment: Basically, `PlotRange -> All`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code does not match the equation at the top of the post.

```
sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + 
     3 x'[t] Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4] + 
     Sqrt[3/2] Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]] (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]]) == 0, 
   x'[0] == -0.010327936857938202, x[0] == 5.352343521285111}, 
  x, {t, 0, 150}]
```

```
Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol], {t, 0., 150.}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[{x[t], x'[t]} /. sol, {t, 1, 150}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AspectRatio -> .6]
```

[image]